# How do you delete a dictionary from a list of dictionaries?

Tags: python, dictionary

How do you delete a dictionary from a list of dictionaries? I have tried:

```
if data == []:
        print("No questions saved")
    else:
        while True:
            myDeletenumber = input("Which question do you want to delete?")
            try:
                myDeletenumber = int(myDeletenumber)
                myDeletenumber -= 1
                data.pop(myDeletenumber)
                break
            except ValueError:
                print('Not a number!')
                continue
```

In this situation `data` is the list of dictionaries

Comment: Do you get an error?

Comment: What is your problem? I didn't run it, but this code looks fine.

Comment: well you have a syntax error on the `data.pop` line.

Comment: try this `data.pop(myDeletenumber)` .

Comment: Not only is your code poorly indented, it contains `break` and `continue` outside a loop.

Comment: Bad way to solution

Comment: @Abdou sorry it is in a loop, just the loop is outside the snippet i am showing you.

Answer (score 1):

A simpler way to do it might be to use `del data[myDeleteNumber]`

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative, if your data structure is large, you might consider assigning None instead of popping from the middle of it.

```
myDeletenumber = input("Which question do you want to delete?")

try:
    myDeletenumber = int(myDeletenumber)
    myDeletenumber -= 1
    data[myDeletenumber] = None
    break        # <-- we'll assume that this snippet is inside a loop here...
except ValueError:
    print('Not a number!')
    continue
```

That prevents a copy of the entirety of the elements placed after the deleted element, and avoids changing the index at which the elements reside (which seems to be important knowledge that the user needs to manipulate the data in the present case)

Answer (score 0):

It's `data.pop(myDeletenumber)`, with parenthesis, not square brackets.

Answer (score 0):

No of ways to do so, go for good approach

```
myDeletenumber = input("Which question do you want to delete?")
try:
    del data[int(myDeletenumber)-1]
except KeyError:
    print ('No number exist')
```

you can try this:

```
try:
    data.pop(int(myDeletenumber)-1)
except KeyError:
    print ('No number exist')
```